Error When Publishing to LinkedIn via API - Code: 422
I'm encountering an error when publishing to LinkedIn via their API. Here are the details:
Error code: 422
Response:
{
    "message": "ERROR :: /author :: \"urn:li:person:aba2390d-7792-4cb2-ad6b-e116d9783606\" does not match urn:li:company:\\d+|urn:li:member:\\d+\n",
    "status": 422
}


Context
Request type: POST
API URL: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts
Payload:
{
  "author": "urn:li:person:aba2390d-7792-4cb2-ad6b-e116d9783606",
  "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
  "specificContent": {
    "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
      "shareCommentary": {
        "text": "Here is the content of my post."
      },
      "shareMediaCategory": "ARTICLE",
      "media": [
        {
          "status": "READY",
          "originalUrl": "https://www.example.com/article",
          "title": {
            "text": "Example Article"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "visibility": {
    "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
  }
}


Here is my code:
def linkedin_login(request):
    auth_url = f"https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id={settings.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri={settings.LINKEDIN_REDIRECT_URI}&scope=w_member_social"
    return redirect(auth_url)

def linkedin_callback(request):
    if 'error' in request.GET:
        error = request.GET.get('error')
        error_description = request.GET.get('error_description')
        return render(request, 'error.html', {'error': error, 'description': error_description})

    code = request.GET.get('code')
    if not code:
        return render(request, 'error.html', {'error': 'No code provided'})

    # Exchange the code for a token
    token_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken'
    data = {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': code,
        'redirect_uri': settings.LINKEDIN_REDIRECT_URI,
        'client_id': settings.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': settings.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET
    }
    response = requests.post(token_url, data=data)
    
    if response.status_code != 200:
        return render(request, 'error.html', {'error': 'Failed to obtain access token', 'description': response.text})

    token_data = response.json()
    access_token = token_data.get('access_token')
    expires_in = token_data.get('expires_in', 3600)  # default to 1 hour if not provided

    # Generate a unique identifier for this token
    linkedin_id = str(uuid.uuid4())

    # If the user is not authenticated, create a new user or log them in
    if request.user.is_anonymous:
        # Create a new user with a unique username
        username = f"linkedin_user_{linkedin_id[:8]}"
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=None)
        login(request, user)
    else:
        user = request.user

    # Create or update the LinkedIn account
    LinkedInProfile.objects.update_or_create(
        user=user,
        defaults={
            'linkedin_id': linkedin_id,
            'access_token': access_token,
            'expires_at': timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(seconds=expires_in)
        }
    )

    return redirect('dashboard')

def dashboard(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('linkedin_login_page')
    
    scheduled_posts = LinkedInPost.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('scheduled_time')
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'scheduled_posts': scheduled_posts})

def linkedin_login_page(request):
    return render(request, 'linkedin_login.html')

def error(requests):
    return render(requests, "error.html")

def create_linkedin_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        scheduled_time_str = request.POST.get('scheduled_time')
        
        # Convert the date/time string to a datetime object
        if scheduled_time_str:
            scheduled_time = parse_datetime(scheduled_time_str)
            if scheduled_time:
                # Check if the date is naive or already timezone aware
                if timezone.is_naive(scheduled_time):
                    scheduled_time = timezone.make_aware(scheduled_time, timezone.get_current_timezone())
                # If it's already timezone aware, we don't need to modify it
            else:
                # Handle the case where parse_datetime returns None (invalid format)
                return redirect('error_page')  # Or another appropriate page
        else:
            scheduled_time = None
        
        try:
            linkedin_profile = LinkedInProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        except LinkedInProfile.DoesNotExist:
            # Handle the case where the user doesn't have a LinkedIn profile
            return redirect('error_page')  # Or another appropriate page
        
        post = LinkedInPost.objects.create(
            user=request.user,
            content=content,
            scheduled_time=scheduled_time,
            linkedin_profile=linkedin_profile,
            is_published=True  # or False, depending on your business logic
        )
        
        # Publish immediately if no future date is specified
        now = timezone.now()
        if not scheduled_time or scheduled_time <= now:
            post.publish_to_linkedin()
        
    return redirect('dashboard')

# My models
class LinkedInProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    access_token = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    expires_at = models.DateTimeField()
    linkedin_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)  # Changed to 20 to accommodate numeric IDs

    def __str__(self):
        return f"LinkedIn Profile of {self.user.username}"

class LinkedInPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    scheduled_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    posted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    aware_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    linkedin_profile = models.ForeignKey(LinkedInProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.scheduled_time:
            if timezone.is_naive(self.scheduled_time):
                self.aware_datetime = timezone.make_aware(self.scheduled_time, timezone.get_current_timezone())
            else:
                self.aware_datetime = self.scheduled_time
        super(LinkedInPost, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def publish_to_linkedin(self):
        if self.is_published and not self.posted:
            try:
                url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts"
                headers = {
                    "X-Restli-Protocol-Version": "2.0.0",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Authorization": f"Bearer {self.linkedin_profile.access_token}"
                }
                
                # Use the correct format for the LinkedIn identifier
                author = f"urn:li:person:{self.linkedin_profile.linkedin_id}"
                
                payload = {
                    "author": author,
                    "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
                    "specificContent": {
                        "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
                            "shareCommentary": {
                                "text": self.content
                            },
                            "shareMediaCategory": "NONE"
                        }
                    },
                    "visibility": {
                        "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
                    }
                }

                response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)

                if response.status_code == 201:
                    self.posted = True
                    self.aware_datetime = timezone.now()
                    self.save()
                    return True
                else:
                    print(f"Error when publishing on LinkedIn. Code: {response.status_code}, Response: {response.text}")
                    return False

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error when publishing on LinkedIn: {str(e)}")
                return False
        return False

    def __str__(self):
        return f"LinkedIn Post by {self.user.username} - {self.scheduled_time}"


What I've Tried:

I've checked the author's URN to ensure it is correctly formatted as urn:li:person.
I reviewed LinkedIn's API documentation to confirm the accepted URN formats.

Questions:
What is the correct format for the author's URN?
Are there any other specific considerations for the URN when publishing via the LinkedIn API?
Environment:
Language: Python
Library Used: requests for HTTP requests
